# E185 Cannot find color scheme huzi_python

Tags: macos, vim

This happened when I start the vim in my Macbook:

```
huzi:~ huzi$ vim
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/synload.vim:
line   19:
E185: Cannot find color scheme huzi_python
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

When in synload.vim, it is:

```
" Set the default highlighting colors.  Use a color scheme if specified.
if exists("colors_name")
  exe "colors " . colors_name
else
  runtime! syntax/syncolor.vim
endif
```

Comment: Where did you put `huzi_python.vim`?

Comment: Do you have a line that sets colorcheme to huzi_python? Basically, this configuration is in $HOME/.vimrc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the "huzi_python.vim" into your ".vim" folder into the subfolder "colors".
After that you have to set the following in your ".vimrc":

```
colorscheme huzi_python
```

If you want a dark background within the editing area and syntax highlighting you cann add the following:

```
set background=dark
```

Comment: You could accept my answer if it helped you, thanks.